# Hive UDF for selecting all except some columns

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql, apache-spark-sql, udf

The common query building pattern in HiveQL (and SQL in general) is to either select all columns (`SELECT *`) or an explicitly-specified set of columns (`SELECT A, B, C`). SQL has no built-in mechanism for selecting all but a specified set of columns.

There are various mechanisms for excluding some columns as outlined in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea) but none apply naturally to HiveQL. (For example, the idea to create a temporary table with `SELECT *` then `ALTER TABLE DROP` some of its columns would wreak havoc in a big data environment.)

Ignoring the ideological discussion about whether it is a good idea to select all but some columns, this question is about the possible ways to extend Hive with this capability.

Prior to Hive 0.13.0 SELECT could take regular-expression-based columns, e.g., `property_.*` inside a backtick-quoted string. @invoketheshell's answer below refers to this capability but it comes at a cost, which is that, when this capability is on, Hive cannot accept columns with non-standard characters in them, e.g., `$foo` or `x/y`. That's why the Hive developers turned this behavior off by default in 0.13.0. I am looking for a generic solution that works for any column name.

A generic table-generating UDF ([UDTF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-CreatingCustomUDFs)) could certainly do this because it can [manipulate the schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982163/create-multiple-columns-from-single-hive-udf). Since we are not going to generate new rows, is there a way to solve this problem using a simple row-based UDF?

This seems like a common problem with many posts around the Web showing how to solve it for various databases yet I haven't been able to find a solution for Hive. Is there code somewhere that does this?

Comment: This unresolved bug may cause problems, since it means you couldn't do a UDF e.g. all_except(*, excluded_column1, excluded_column2)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1459

Comment: Thanks @mattinbits. I voted for the issue and encourage others to do so as well.

Answer (score 9):

You can choose every column except those listed in a regex based specification.  This is query columns by exclusion.  See below:

A SELECT statement can take regex-based column specification in Hive releases prior to 0.13.0, or in 0.13.0 and later releases if the configuration property hive.support.quoted.identifiers is set to none.

That being said you could create a new table or view using the following, and all the columns except the columns specified will be returned:

```
hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;    

drop table if       exists database.table_name;
create table if not exists database.table_name as
    select `(column_to_remove_1|...|column_to_remove_N)?+.+`
    from database.some_table
    where 
    --...
;
```

This will create a table that has all the columns from some_table except the columns named column_to_remove_1, ... , to column_to_remove_N. You can also choose to create a view instead.

Comment: You make a good point but the behavior you describe is not generic as it disallows columns with non-standard characters in them, which is why it is disabled by default in 0.13.0 and later versions. I have updated the question to clarify that I seek a behavior that does not depend on this setting.

Comment: One suggestion: in the version of Hive sql I run at work, we have to add the keyword `set` in front of  `hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none; `.