# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10036]: Duplicate column name: p_id

Tags: mysql, view, hive, hiveql

when

```
SELECT * from hospital_basic 
LEFT JOIN hospital_clinical on hospital_basic.p_id=hospital_clinical.p_id;
```

It is working fine but when creating view it is giving error

```
CREATE VIEW hospital_view AS
SELECT * from hospital_basic LEFT JOIN 
hospital_clinical on hospital_basic.p_id=hospital_clinical.p_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to put an alias for the columns that you are selecting, you cannot do `select *` because the column p_id will be duplicated for the table definition

```
CREATE VIEW hospital_view AS 
SELECT 
hospital_basic.p_id as hospital_basic_p_id,
hospital_clinical.p_id as hospital_clinical_p_id,
other columns   ...
from hospital_basic LEFT JOIN hospital_clinical on hospital_basic.p_id=hospital_clinical.p_id;
```

Comment: so, if together both have 20 column, I have to write it all?

Comment: you can use regular expressions to exclude all but one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666905/hive-udf-for-selecting-all-except-some-columns